# Can't use https on localhost

Tags: linux-mint, apache-httpd, ssl, https

I am unable to use https on my localhost test machine. I can't figure out the problem on my own so here is what i did:

I placed the following to files in sites-available :
000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel debug

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

default-ssl.conf

```
[default-ssl.conf Pastebin Link][1]
```

cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled

sudo ln -s ../mods-available/rewrite.load rewrite.load

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

a2ensite default-ssl

However when trying to use https I revice

> Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

ports.conf:

```
Listen 80
<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Using `openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 </dev/null`
Gives me:

> connect: Connection refused connect:errno=111
> So APache is not listenning on 443, but it should be based on the ports.conf?

An suggestions? Let me know if you need more informations.

UPDATE:

```
    [Mon Mar 09 12:01:55.092346 2015] [ssl:info] [pid 7091] AH02200: Loading certificate & private key of SSL-aware server '127.0.1.1:443'
[Mon Mar 09 12:01:55.092520 2015] [ssl:debug] [pid 7091] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(506): AH02249: unencrypted RSA private key - pass phrase not required
[Mon Mar 09 12:01:55.092532 2015] [ssl:debug] [pid 7091] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(181): AH02199: SSL not enabled on vhost 127.0.1.1:80, skipping SSL setup
[Mon Mar 09 12:01:55.092546 2015] [ssl:info] [pid 7091] AH01914: Configuring server 127.0.1.1:443 for SSL protocol
[Mon Mar 09 12:01:55.092658 2015] [ssl:debug] [pid 7091] ssl_engine_init.c(328): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
[Mon Mar 09 12:01:55.092661 2015] [ssl:debug] [pid 7091] ssl_engine_init.c(836): AH02232: Configuring RSA server certificate
[Mon Mar 09 12:01:55.092705 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 7091] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Mon Mar 09 12:01:55.092731 2015] [ssl:debug] [pid 7091] ssl_util_ssl.c(407): AH02412: [127.0.1.1:443] Cert does not match for name '127.0.1.1' [subject: emailAddress=asd,CN=asd,OU=asd,O=asd,L=ads,ST=asd,C=DE / issuer: emailAddress=asd,C$
[Mon Mar 09 12:01:55.092734 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 7091] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for 127.0.1.1:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Mar 09 12:01:55.092736 2015] [ssl:debug] [pid 7091] ssl_engine_init.c(891): AH02236: Configuring RSA server private key
```

Comment: Did you look at the error log of the server? And since IfModule will ignore the lines if the module is not installed - are you sure you either have ssl_module or mod_gnutls installed?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i switched all Logging to Debug but there is non created when trying to access a site

Comment: You need to create a certificate. Have you done that?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i updated the post.

Comment: @FaheemMitha i did.

Comment: You don't have any virtualhost defined on port 443, only on 80 AFAICS

Comment: @wurtel Editor broke my default-ssl.conf -> Link to pastebin http://pastebin.com/HT1wB4Hh

Comment: That can't be right either, I count 7 VIrtualhost starts but just one end. pastepastepastepastepastepastebin?

Comment: @wurtel whups http://pastebin.com/KD1VYcFT

Comment: localhost is usually 127.0.0.1, but you configure the server at 127.0.1.1. Check with `netstat -nltp | grep 443` where your listener is and connect to this IP.

Comment: Looks OK. Did you try stopping en starting apache? Reloading is not always sufficient. Also I always remove the conditional `IFModule` stuff: if the module isn't loaded I want a fatal error instead of silently not doing what I want, esp. with `ssl_module`.

Comment: @wurteli stopped apache, reloaded, tryed to start but it now fails. Only thing in the error.log is this: [Mon Mar 09 12:45:55.936825 2015] [ssl:debug] [pid 8798] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(181): AH02199: SSL not enabled on vhost 127.0.1.1:80, skipping SSL setup

Comment: Isn't your firewall enabled? If it is, is just a matter of create an input rule: `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT` - **edit:** Nevermind. It is a localhost connection so it shouldn't have a firewall enabled on it